# My first AJAX script no result

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Good day

I am trying to write my 1st AJAX script, which I did with assistance from:
[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

Unfortunately I cant progress to the next chapter since my current script is not working, and I cant for the live of me spot the error, any help would be welcomed.

```
    <script>
    function showSport(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
    </script>

    <form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showSport(this.value)">
      <option value="">Select a Sport:</option>
      <option value="Rugby">Rugby</option>
      <option value="Cricket">Cricket</option>
      <option value="Football">Football</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Sport info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

And here is my PHP file getdata.php

```
 <?php
include'connect.php';
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE sport_type = '".$q."'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Competition</th>
<th>Home Team</th>
<th>Away Team</th>
<th>Event Date</th>

</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['competition'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['team1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['team2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['event_date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

my connect.php file is working because I use it on all my other scripts and my database table events is populated with all data im requesting.

When I run the script only the table headers gets displayed without any info inside the table i.e I get a blank table back.

Any help welcomed

Comment: In your PHP... how are you setting `$q`?

Comment: Where's `$q = intval($_GET['q']);` ?

Comment: let me check I think Ive got it just made a copy and paste error, will let you know now, thanks guys

Comment: @diggersworld please see update I omitted it in the copy and paste to SO, still no data to table....

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` need a `mysqli_result` instance, but you use `mysql_query` to get the resource. Choose your [api](https://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing).

Comment: @Leggendario thanks Ill give it a go but thats not how they have it in the tutorial at w3schools

Comment: are you sure `str` has a value when you make the AJAX request? Try putting `console.log(str);` on the line before your `xmlhttp.open("GET", "getdata.php?q=" + str, true);`

Comment: @diggersworld will do now and let you know. Firefox gives me the following: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
});

Comment: @diggersworld nothing gets returned with console.log(str);....I cant understand since this is exactly like tutorials example

Comment: That `SyntaxError` indicates that you have some invalid JavaScript syntax. Might be worth checking your nesting, brackets, and semicolons. If nothing is returned from the `console.log()` this reveals that `str` has no value. Hence why when you query the database, it finds no results.

Comment: Also... your backend code is expecting an integer `intval($_GET['q'])` but your values for the select options are all strings `Rugby`, `Cricket`, etc.

Comment: @diggersworld thanks will investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here mysql and mysqli is different.
you cannot use both function at same time. 
It depends on which function you had used in your connection file(In your case connect.php).  mysql_connect() or mysqli_connect() use only that function throughout your project. That's why you can't getting desired output.
If you use mysql_connect() then don't use mysqli instance for executing query or for fetch results.